# Relationship direction through the REST API

Tags: rest, neo4j

Is it possible to define a relationship direction (api.neo4j.org/1.9.M05/org/neo4j/graphdb/Direction.html) using the REST API?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, start from the starting node and send the JSON description of the new relationship with the `to` field pointing to the destination node. See [the documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/snapshot/rest-api-relationships.html#rest-api-create-relationship).

Comment: But how do i specify a both incoming/outgoing direction?

Comment: Wow, it seems there's no way using REST, however there's no performance difference wrt traversing direction, and REST traverser allow to set `direction` to `all`, so it can be circumvented. 
Still, it's strange, you could ask on Neo4j newsletter.

Comment: Also in the embedded API there is no way of creating a relationship in _both_ directions. The enum value is just there for queries.

Comment: I didn't know, I've just discovered a wrapper I wrote years ago accepted BOTH as directionship but internally used OUTGOING. Goods to know